# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: './cogs'

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a discord bot and just implemented COGS into it to organize my code. I have the cogs folder in the same folder as my main.py but it raises the **FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: './cogs'** error when I try to run the code. I dont know how to fix this.

This is the main.py

```
import discord
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands

# Client
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-')
client.remove_command("help")

# Cog Functions
@client.command()
async def load(context, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command()
async def unload(context, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

# Run the client on the server
load_dotenv('.env.txt')
client.run(os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN'))
```

This is the file where i am trying to implement a cog

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime

class GeneralCommands(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    def setup(self, client)
        client.add_cog(GeneralCommands(client))
```

Comment: You say you have a "cogs folder", but you paste a "cogs file". Which one is it?

Comment: i worded it incorrectly. the "cogs file" is where i put my cog that im trying to load

Comment: Can you show the actual filenames of these files? Also, make sure your `cogs/` directory has an `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
os.listdir('cogs')
```

Instead of:

```
os.listdir('./cogs')
```