# FileNotFoundError: The system cannot find the path specified: 'D:\\MS Data\\CI Papers\\My Paper\\LungCancerDataset\\Benign_cases'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have been trying to load the data in my jupyter notebook but getting the FileNotFoundError error repeatedly. Since i am new to it and facing difficulties. I have a folder LungCancerDataset and 3 sub folders named Bengin_cases, Malignant_cases and Normal_cases

I want to load them and preprocess to use with Alexnet for classification

folder screen shot:
[image]

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

dataset_path = r'D:\MS Data\CI Papers\My Paper\LungCancerDataset'

def load_and_preprocess_images(folder_path):
    images = []
    labels = []

# Iterate over files in the folder
for label, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(folder_path)):
    # Construct the full path to the image file
    image_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)

    # Read the image using OpenCV
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)

    # Check if the image was successfully loaded
    if image is not None:
        # Resize image to 227x227 (AlexNet input size)
        image = cv2.resize(image, (227, 227))

        # Normalize pixel values to range [0, 1]
        image = image.astype('float32') / 255.0

        # Append the image and its label to the lists
        images.append(image)
        labels.append(label)  # Assign label based on folder (0: normal, 1: benign, 2: malignant)

return images, labels

normal_images, normal_labels = load_and_preprocess_images(os.path.join(dataset_path, 'Normal_cases'))
benign_images, benign_labels = load_and_preprocess_images(os.path.join(dataset_path, 'Benign_cases'))
malignant_images, malignant_labels = load_and_preprocess_images(os.path.join(dataset_path, 'Malignant_cases'))
```

THE ERROR MESSAGE

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-8858f2466543> in <module>
      1 normal_images, normal_labels = load_and_preprocess_images(os.path.join(dataset_path, 'Normal_cases'))
----> 2 benign_images, benign_labels = load_and_preprocess_images(os.path.join(dataset_path, 'Benign_cases'))
      3 malignant_images, malignant_labels = load_and_preprocess_images(os.path.join(dataset_path, 'Malignant_cases'))

<ipython-input-6-ae38c4e28bac> in load_and_preprocess_images(folder_path)
      4 
      5     # Iterate over files in the folder
----> 6     for label, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(folder_path)):
      7         # Construct the full path to the image file
      8         image_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'D:\\MS Data\\CI Papers\\My Paper\\LungCancerDataset\\Benign_cases'
```

I tried to take help from chat gpt but didn't work [(chat link)](https://chat.openai.com/share/453b37e9-3318-4fde-b002-395bb6c00fb4)
Tried to find some questions from here but they didn't work ([question_link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68713437/filenotfounderror-winerror-3-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-co)) ([Quesiton_link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51007476/filenotfounderror-winerror-3-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified?rq=2))

Comment: The error means exactly what it says: that directory does not exist.

Comment: The folder is having 3 sub folders do know whats wrong

Comment: The function call for `Normal_cases` appears to have worked, so is the `Benign_cases` subfolder in exactly that same place?

Comment: yes it is in same place

Comment: Well, then I can't explain it.  The error message clearly says that it doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you show us the output of this code `print(os.listdir(dataset_path))`

Comment: The folder name is misspelled.  It is actually `Bengin`, not `Benign`.

Comment: Here it is  ['Bengin_cases', 'IQ-OTH_NCCD lung cancer dataset.txt', 'Malignant_cases', 'Normal_cases', 'The Iraq data set.docx']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You spelled the folder name `Bengin` wrong, it doesn't match your code, which uses `Benign`.

*This has been stated by [@John Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494134/john-gordon) in the comments as well.*

Always make your file names match the name of what you are trying to find.